# An Application of Cauchy Mean Value Theorem

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

For calculating the following expression, Gauss' Mean Value Theorem is used. The result is nonzero. However, when I make substitution and say $e^{i\theta}=u$, I find the result to be zero since the boundary of the integral becomes from $1$ to $1$. Where am I mistaken? Thanks in advance.
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \sin^3 (3e^{i\theta} + \pi/4)d\theta$$

Comment: When you put $u = e^{i\theta}$, $[0,2\pi]$ maps to the unit circle.

Comment: @mrf I would like to say "This sine function is holomorphic, so triple power is also holomorphic, therefore it has a primitive, so by Cauchy's formula, on a closed curve which does not wind around an isolated singularity, the integral is zero." However I can not be sure whether unit circle contains an isolated singularity. I need to solve $cos\theta + isin\theta = \pi / 4$, but I think it can not have a solution, there is no angle whose cosine is equal to $\pi / 4$ and sine is zero.

Comment: With $z = e^{i\theta}$, your integral is $$\frac{1}{i}\int_{\lvert z\rvert = 1} \frac{\sin^3 (3z+\pi/4)}{z}\,dz.$$

Comment: apply cauchy integral theorem to it then the answer will be $\pi / \sqrt{2}$

Comment: @Daniel Fischer So $dx+idy=ie^{i\theta}d\theta$? How to proceed then?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. The integral formula gives you the result when the integral is written in complex form.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer The question is I am unable to pass to Cauchy Integral Formula.

Comment: Try from the other end then. Start with $$\frac{1}{i}\int_{\lvert z\rvert = 1} \frac{\sin^3 (3z+\pi/4)}{z}\,dz$$ and parametrise the unit circle with $\kappa(t) = e^{it}$.

Comment: we can apply the cauchy integral formula on the above written formula @DanielFischer

Comment: @Boris Yes, of course. I interpreted the OP's comment so that they can't connect the real form of the integral from the question with the complex form in the comments, and going from the complex form to the real form via the parametrisation is automatic.

Comment: @Boris and Daniel Fischer Thank you so much, I did it know.